# How to install SSH2-Lib for PHP7 on Linux Ubuntu Wheezy (raspbian)?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi2, libssh2

I decided to install the new PHP7. Due to the old raspbian repository, it was impossible to `apt-get install` it. Ondrej's ppa wouldnt work either, because there is no wheezy upload.

Everything went fine and my Apache is connected with PHP7, so it runs now. But I've found out, that there is no SSH2-Module installed. I need that for dependencies I'm not able to change :/

So here is what I've tried:

```
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-0.12.tgz
tar -xzf ssh2-0.12.tgz -C /
phpize
./configure
sudo make && make install
```

--> pecl/ssh2 requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.0.0RC4

Okay, there seems to be a problem with my PHP-Version. So i searched for it and found out. there is a new versio available at https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-ssh2/pull/7

So I downloaded this, installed this and then tried

```
pecl install -f ssh2
```

Then this PECL decided to download the original 0.12 Version which i already tried above. Nice miracle.

Any help is VERY appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites, either http://askubuntu.com or http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Good luck.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://medium.com/php-7-tutorial/solution-how-to-compile-php7-with-ssh2-f23de4e9c319

Comment: don't work for me, on debian

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pecl install ssh2-1.1.2
```

You can check which version to use HERE

For those using alpine linux, make sure to add libssh2-dev first:

```
apk --update add libssh2-dev
```